# What is the song playing in My Name Is Earl S4E4?

Tags: soundtrack, my-name-is-earl

I'm trying to find the name of the song that plays between 04:12 - 04:40 of the episode of My Name Is Earl (Stole an RV), which is the 4th episode of season 4.

In case the minutes do not match, the scene I mean is where Earl fixes the roof of the man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't normally ID songs here, so this question will probably be closed. However, the song you're after is Blue Oyster Cult's [(Don't Fear) The Reaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28Don%27t_Fear%29_The_Reaper) from their 1976 album *Agents of Fortune*. It's apropos because the old, tired man whose roof Earl fixes welcomes death. Here's the song, cowbell and all: